# Vaadin EntityManager NullReferenceException

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm trying to make a program work in vaadin & spring-boot, but can't make EntityManager work. Getting a NullReferenceException

For starters, this is my firs try making something using Spring-boot and Vaadin. 
I am trying to make EntityManager work, but I'm getting a NullReferenceException.
It seems my EntityManager is throwing the exception, but I can't find any examples on how to use it properly.
I thought about using EntityManagerFactory, but again, no examples anywhere..
The findAll() method works, so I'm not sure what to do.

I have a Repository_Room interface

```
public interface Repository_Room
{
    void save(Room room);

    void delete(Room room);

    void update(Room room);

    List<Room> findAll();

    List<Course> getCourses(Room room);
}
```

Implementing it in Repository_Room_Impl class

```java
@Transactional
@Repository
public class Repository_Room_Impl implements Repository_Room{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Repository_Room_Impl()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public List<Room> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select n from " + Room.class.getSimpleName() + " n").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Room room) {
        em.persist(room);
    }

    public void delete(Room room) {
        em.remove(em.find(Room.class, room.getId()));
    }

    public void update(Room room) {
        em.merge(em);
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses(Room room)
    {
        List<Course> courses = em.createQuery("select n from " + Course.class.getSimpleName() + " n WHERE n.Room = :roomID", Course.class)
                .setParameter("roomID", room.getId())
                .getResultList();
        return courses;
    }
}
```

Trying to use the repository in my form to add a new element

```java
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class Form_Room extends VerticalLayout {

    private Room room;

    private Reloader reloader;

    private TextField val_id;
    private TextField val_name;
    private TextField val_level;

    private Binder<Room> binder;

    @Autowired
    private Repository_Room repository;

    public Form_Room()
    {
        binder = new Binder<>(Room.class);

        val_id = new TextField("ID:");
        val_name = new TextField("Name:");
        val_level = new TextField(("Level:"));

        binder.forField(val_id)
                .withConverter(
                        new StringToIntegerConverter("Must enter a number"))
                .bind(Room::getId, Room::setId);

        binder.forField(val_name).bind(Room::getName, Room::setName);

        binder.forField(val_level)
                .withConverter(
                        new StringToIntegerConverter("Must enter a number"))
                .bind(Room::getLevel, Room::setLevel);

        add(val_id);
        add(val_name);
        add(val_level);
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        if (room == null) {
            this.room = null;
        }
        else {
            this.room = room;
            binder.readBean(this.room);
        }
    }

    public Reloader getReloader() {
        return reloader;
    }

    public void setReloader(Reloader reloader) {
        this.reloader = reloader;
    }

    public void updateRoom()
    {
        try
        {
            if(room == null)
            {
                repository.save(this.room);
                System.out.println("Created");
            }
            else
            {
                binder.writeBean(this.room);
                repository.update(this.room);
                System.out.println("Updated");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This form is created in my view

```java
@Route(value = "rooms")
public class View_CRUD_Room extends VerticalLayout implements Reloader{

    @Autowired
    private Repository_Room repository;

    @Autowired
    private Form_Room form;

    private Grid<Room> grid;
    private Button button_view;
    private Button button_remove;
    private Button button_execute;
    private HorizontalLayout buttonLayout;

    private Room selected;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        form = new Form_Room();
        grid = new Grid<>();
        button_view = new Button();
        button_remove = new Button();
        buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        selected = null;

        button_execute = new Button();
        button_execute.setText("Végrehajt");

        button_view.setText("Részletek");
        button_remove.setText("Töröl");
        buttonLayout.add(button_view);
        buttonLayout.add(button_remove);

        form.setVisible(true);

        button_execute.addClickListener(event -> {
            form.updateRoom();
        });

        button_view.addClickListener(event -> {
            // Display details
        });

        button_remove.addClickListener(event -> {
            // Display form with confirmation message and YesNo buttons
        });

        List<Room> list = repository.findAll();
        grid.setItems(repository.findAll());
        grid.addColumn(Room::getId).setHeader("Id");
        grid.addColumn(Room::getName).setHeader("Name");
        grid.addColumn(Room::getLevel).setHeader("Terem");
        grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(selectionEvent -> {
            if (selectionEvent.getValue() != null) {
                selected = selectionEvent.getValue();
                form.setRoom(selected);
            } else {
                selected = null;
                form.setRoom(selected);
            }
        });
        add(new Text("Termek"));
        add(grid);
        add(buttonLayout);
        add(form);
        add(button_execute);
    }

    @Override
    public void processRefresh() {
        grid.setItems(repository.findAll());
    }
}
```

The stackTrace prints the following:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.beadando.repository.Impl.Repository_Room_Impl.save(Repository_Room_Impl.java:26)
    at com.example.beadando.component.Form_Room.updateRoom(Form_Room.java:93)
    at com.example.beadando.view.View_CRUD_Room.lambda$init$9b1b5227$1(View_CRUD_Room.java:55)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:420)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:420)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:387)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:310)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1507)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I modified the setRoom() method to try to add a new element without having to deal with my TextFields.
Getting NullReferenceException in the form when trying to call my updateRoom() method.
Please point me in the right direction..
Thank you!

Comment: try replacing the "@Repository" annotation with just a "@Component" annotation and see if that works

Comment: That didn't help, unfortunately. Still the same NullReferenceException is thrown at em.persist() in repository.save()

Comment: By quick glance there is several problems in your code. For example you are instantiating the repository in Form_Room with new, and you have it @Autowired in that class. You should refactor the code. Also I see you newer read or set the bean to Binder, so what ever you edit is not going to be saved, since there is no bean in your form.

Comment: To add to what Tatu said, the reason `findAll()` works is that in your view, you don't initialize the repository manually, instead letting Spring inject it for you, and at the same time inject the entity manager into the repository. In your form, however, you initialize it manually, which means Spring no longer manages it, and can not inject your entity manager for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i was a bit too fast when looking before.

But this is your problem, you are creating the autowired classes yourself instead of letting Spring create them for you.

```
@Autowired
private Repository_Room repository;

public Form_Room() {
    repository = new Repository_Room_Impl(); //remove this line

    //rest of the code
}
```

And here you do it again in your view:

```
@Route(value = "rooms")
public class View_CRUD_Room extends VerticalLayout implements Reloader {

@PostConstruct
private void init(){
    form = new Form_Room(); //remove this line

    //rest of the code
}
```

You see autowire is something called Dependency Injection. This is a fancy word for saying that "the framwork" (in this case spring) will do all the instantiation of classes for you.

Spring will do the "new" for you. And inject in a class during runtime for you to use so you dont have to. Spring will also before it does a "new RepositoryImpl()" will check what dependencies that class has and see that it needs an EntityManager, and instantiate one automagically for you and put that into the RepositoryImpl.

Thats the whole point of using Autowire, that you dont have to do the new. You just have to trust that there will be class there when you use it.

Then some other pointers about your code.

In java we use camel caseing so instead of "Repository_Room" it should be "RepositoryRoom" same goes for "Repository_Room_Impl" should be "RepositoryRoomImpl"

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it got clear how autowired works, but even if I remove that line, and let the repository get autowired, I still get my exception at the same place ( repository.update ) but I can't find why, upon selecting a row, I call setRoom to set the variable used in update.

Comment: Restored setRoom to the previous code and trying to test only the update method where an existing item is modified using my form but it is still throwing the exception.

Comment: when you debug, is it "Repository_Room" that is null? or is it EntityManager that is null, or is it this.room that is null?

Comment: repository is null. this.room has a value. So the exception is thrown before trying to merge.

Comment: if you run the application in debug you should be able to see in the logs if it manages to find you repository and create it.

Comment: All I get in the debug is the following:2019-06-09 20:22:01.792 DEBUG 5148 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0", parameters={masked}
2019-06-09 20:22:01.793 DEBUG 5148 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@49bb808f
2019-06-09 20:22:01.807 DEBUG 5148 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

Comment: 2019-06-09 20:22:01.843 DEBUG 5148 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0", parameters={masked}
2019-06-09 20:22:01.843 DEBUG 5148 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@49bb808f

Comment: The strange thing is, it works in my view but not in the form, despite being autowired at both places.

Comment: i have update my answer, you need to remove another line

Comment: Jeez. You were right, I havent noticed that was autowired too. Got a new exception but I hope I can solve this one. Unknown Entity: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87. Thank you, i'm trying :)

Comment: no worries, pls accept my answer as the right one, and ask a new question if you get stuck